# Numpy complaining about ambigoous array: ValueError: The truth value of

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a minimal code in Python 3, which uses numpy and the function `apply_along_axis`. I cannot understand the reason I am having this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Providing a direct formula inside the `lambda` is working. As soon as I use another function, I am getting this error. Am I supposed to return something else?

---

The minimal code:

```py
import numpy as np

def logn(x, b):
    return np.log(x)/np.log(b)
def h(x, b):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return -x*logn(x, b)

p = np.array([0.00000000e+00, 9.99997956e-01, 2.04440466e-06])
print(np.apply_along_axis(lambda _e: h(_e, 3), -1, p))
```

Comment: you compare x with 0 ( x == 0) . Where x is probably a matrix or list. So numpy compares every element in the matrix/list . And then python tries to determine the truth value of that matrix/list . Which it can't . That's why this error happens.

Comment: `p` is one dimensional array. `x` is supposed to be a scalar. if I try `p[0] == 0`, I don't have any error. Actually, If I remove `if` and use return directly, it's no longer causing errors. Also, adding x[0] solved the error as well.

Comment: Why are you using `apply_along_axis` instead of a simple loop?  Make sure you understand what `apply` passes.  It's not as useful a function as you mighr think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what `apply_along_axis` passes to your function:

```
In [99]: def foo(x): 
    ...:     print(x) 
    ...:     return x 
    ...:                                                                                 
In [100]: np.apply_along_axis(foo, -1, p)                                                
[0.00000000e+00 9.99997956e-01 2.04440466e-06]
Out[100]: array([0.00000000e+00, 9.99997956e-01, 2.04440466e-06])
```

In the case of a 1d array, it passes the **whole** array at once.  It does not iterate on that dimension.  That's whole purpose of `apply_along_axis` - to pass 1d arrays to your function.

Judging from other SO `apply_along_axis` is not very useful, and often gives problems. It is not faster than a more explicit iteration.  For 3d (or higher) it can make the iteration (over the 'other' two axes) simpler (but again not faster).

For the 1d `p`, this is simpler:

```
In [102]: [h(_e,3) for _e in p]                                                          
Out[102]: [0, 1.8605270777946112e-06, 2.4378506521338855e-05]
```

A non-iterative approach is to use a boolean mask to select which `p` are used in the calculation.  That way you don't have to use a scalar `if` expression:

```
In [106]: mask = p!=0                                                                    
In [107]: mask                                                                           
Out[107]: array([False,  True,  True])
In [108]: p1 = p[mask]                                                                   
In [109]: res = np.zeros(p.shape)                                                        
In [110]: res[mask] = -p1*logn(p1,3)                                                     
In [111]: res                                                                            
Out[111]: array([0.00000000e+00, 1.86052708e-06, 2.43785065e-05])
```

`ufunc` like `np.log` take a `where` parameter, which can be used to bypass bad input values:

```
In [114]: -p * np.log(p, where=(p!=0), out=np.zeros(p.shape))/np.log(3)                  
Out[114]: array([-0.00000000e+00,  1.86052708e-06,  2.43785065e-05])
```

Comment: I thought this function would be faster. My rationale was I would pass a numpy array and get back a numpy array without any convertion. I did not realise it actually passes the whole 1D array on which your point makes sense! Thank you for that.

Comment: Also I did not realise I can use where inside functions. These are great advices.